# Extracting version number at the end of a filename with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of filenames, some of which end with a version number at the end. I'm trying to extract the version number using a single regular expression:

```
filename.doc --> NULL
filename.1.0.doc --> 1.0
filename.2.0.pdf --> 2.0
filename.3.0.docx --> 3.0
```

So far, I found that the following regex extracts it along with the extension:

```regex
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.(docx|pdf|rtf|doc|docm)$
```

But I'd rather not have the extension. So what I'm searching is for the `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` just before the last occurrence of a dot in the string, but I can't find how to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may use `r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=\.[^.]*$)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I'm searching is for the `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` just before the last occurrence of a dot in the string

You may use

```
r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=\.[^.]*$)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/el7yNM/1).

**Details**

- `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` - 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?=\.[^.]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `.`, then 0+ chars other than `.` and the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5B0-9%5D%2B%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5C.%5B%5E.%5D*%24)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python regexs have [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups):

> A more significant feature is named groups: instead of referring to them by numbers, groups can be referenced by a name.
>
> The syntax for a named group is one of the Python-specific extensions: (?P...). name is, obviously, the name of the group. Named groups behave exactly like capturing groups, and additionally associate a name with a group. The match object methods that deal with capturing groups all accept either integers that refer to the group by number or strings that contain the desired group’s name. Named groups are still given numbers, so you can retrieve information about a group in two ways:
>
> ```
> >> p = re.compile(r'(?P<word>\b\w+\b)')
> >> m = p.search( '(((( Lots of punctuation )))' )
> >> m.group('word')
> 'Lots'
> >> m.group(1)
> 'Lots'
> ```

So in your case you can modify your regex as:

`(?P<version>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\.(docx|pdf|rtf|doc|docm)$`

and use:

`found.group('version')`

to select version from the found regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
import re

try:
    version = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', 'filename.1.0.doc')][0]
    print(version)
except:
    pass
```

Here, if it has a number, then it will store it in the variable version, else it will pass.

This shoud work! :)